# Using django template tags from one app in another

Tags: django-views, django-templates, templatetags

I have many apps in my django project. I have a template_tag in one of the app. The purpose of this template tag is to load the count of items for the side menu.

The side menu appears in many other apps as well.

So, I want to use single template tag from one app in other apps so that the side menu appears with the numbers without rewriting the code.

Currently when I use

```
{% load my_profile_sidemenu_tag %}
```

and then I write

```
{% my_profile_sidemenu_tag self.request.user.id %}
```

it throws

```
expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Any suggestions?